# Does 3600 ram work on a pc that supports 3600 OC?

Tags: memory

I'm looking at [This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07ZPLM1R1) ram and my motherboard is a [MSI B550-A PRO ProSeries Motherboard)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B089CZSQB4). The motherboard supports 3600 OC ram but I want to make sure it's appropriate to use 3600 regardless before I make the purchase.

Newegg says memory is either A-XMP OC MODE or not. DDR4 3600 is a A-XMP OC MODE type. I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: A-XMP is XMP for AMD platforms. XMP is an intel spec. save yourself some headaches and buy ram off this HCL for your motherboard. you will need to know what CPU you are putting in the system, so you can select its memory controller type. https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B550-A-PRO/support#mem . also, buy all the ram you need in a single package. it can reduce the risk of problems, especially when OCing

Comment: @FrankThomas

I'm reading that my i5 3600x accepts up to 3200 mhz but the motherboard accepts axmp ram. Does that mean I can only use up to 3200mhz?


EDIT: Just saw your post. Reading it now.


EDIT2: I want the easiest path to 32 gigs of ram. lol I notice though, that 32 gigs of 3600 is cheaper than 32 of 3200. This is new territory for me though

Comment: The DDR4 specification goes up to 3200MHz, so all DDR4 boards with support for 3200MHz ram will use the JEDEC profiles for SPD. Since you want to exceed 3200, you need to use an alternate SPD profile like XMP/A-XMP/DOCP to run it that fast. You need aall three; mobo, CPU, and RAM modules that support the faster speeds as well. Note that you cannot put an i5 in this motherboard.  Also note, you can put faster RAM in a system than it can handle. it will just be downclocked to the fastest supported SPD profile.